# Manually Persisting to Instance table as like PersistableIdleAction.Unload

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow inside a transaction so the code in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489463.aspx) is hanging on `WaitOne()` call where I am calling `context.CreateBookmark` method.

Since the workflow in not completed (`syncEvent.set()` is not called) transaction is not getting completed.

But I want to persist the workflow execution until the bookmark part, if I do that by calling syncEvent.Set() on

```
wfApp.PersistableIdle = delegate(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e)
{
    idleEvent.Set();
    return PersistableIdleAction.Persist;
};
```

it is not creating a record in InstanceTable. So I want to persist the workflow manually to InstaceTable or a better way to implement this.

I am using flowchart type workflow

Answer (score 1):

Use the Unloaded event to syncEvent.Set()

Comment: unloaded event will not create persistance to the database